# Eigenvalues of $A^+ A$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, pseudoinverse, singular-values

Let $A \in \mathrm{R}^{n\times m}$ be a matrix of rank $n$ (with $m>n$). Let $A^+$ be the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse of $A$. The matrix

$$ A^+ A = A^T(A A^T)^{-1} A $$

has eigenvalues $\lambda_i \in \{0,1 \}$. How can I proof this?

Comment: Observe that $P:=A^+A$ is a projection, this means $P^2=P.$

Comment: @Fred
Then, defining $P = (p_1,\dots,p_m)$, it holds that $P p_i = p_i$. Hence, I know that the $p_i$'s are eigenvectors of $P$ with eigenvalue $1$. However, that way I still cannot proof that all the eigenvalues of $P$ are $1$ or $0$, right? Do you have another hint?

Comment: Suppose that $ \lambda $ is an eigenvalue of $P$, hence $Px= \lambda x$ for some $x \ne 0.$ This gives $ \lambda x=Px=P^2x=P( \lambda x)= \lambda^2 x$. Hence $\lambda = \lambda^2.$

Comment: Got it, thanks!